# Can I send confidential information in plain text via an HTTPS POST method?

Tags: encryption, tls, network, api, rest

I have a web app that collects user SSN and driver license number. A POST API via HTTPS send the data to the server. Can I use plain text to transfer the data? Is it safe enough? Is it in accordance with the laws in the US?

Comment: Yes, you can pass SSN and driver license # via https and not run afoul of the law.

Comment: If you want a definite answer, you should probably ask a specialized lawyer. Also, the term “plaintext” is a bit confusing in the context of HTTPS, because the whole point of HTTPS is that the data is *not* transmitted as plaintext. Whether transport encryption with HTTPS is sufficient and how exactly the data must be stored are legal questions.

Comment: The devil is in the implementation: using SSL without verifying certificates or ignoring validation errors leaves you open to man in the middle attacks. Also, the channel should not allow downgrade attacks eg switching from https to http.